# Java Threads - Synchronized(this)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Please see the program below

```
public class TestVolatile implements Runnable {

    public static volatile int counter;
    public static String lock = "lock";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new TestVolatile(),"Thread-1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new TestVolatile(),"Thread-2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"-"+counter);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this program multiple times, I get 3 different results.

first is

> Thread[Thread-1,5,main]-0
>   Thread[Thread-2,5,main]-0

second is

> Thread[Thread-1,5,main]-0
>   Thread[Thread-2,5,main]-1

third is

> Thread[Thread-1,5,main]-1
>   Thread[Thread-2,5,main]-0

But if change the lock object from "this" to "lock", I  get 2 different results

first is

> Thread[Thread-1,5,main]-0
>   Thread[Thread-2,5,main]-1

second is

> Thread[Thread-1,5,main]-1
>   Thread[Thread-2,5,main]-0

My assumption when writing the program was that in either case the "counter" should never come 0 in both statements.
Can somebody explain?

Comment: Be careful : ++ is not thread safe as it is in fact 2 operations. See http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2012/01/how-to-write-thread-safe-code-in-java.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create two TestVolatile objects. The "this" keyword refers to the TestVolatile object being run in the thread. Thus you do not synchronize on the same object in the first example.

If you change the code like this, then the first example starts working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestVolatile testVolatile = new TestVolatile();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(testVolatile,"Thread-1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(testVolatile,"Thread-2");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not what you're looking for, but if you want to avoid the use of `synchronized` and `volatile`, you should use an instance of `AtomicInteger`:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Use the `getAndIncrement` method to show the same behavior as in your example.

```
public class TestVolatile implements Runnable {

    public static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new TestVolatile(),"Thread-1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new TestVolatile(),"Thread-2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " - " + counter.getAndIncrement());
    }

}
```